# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to write a program in java, but I have got some problem.
my program is GUI. the program must get ***two*** inputs from user, check they are bigger than 0 and the second one is bigger than the first one.
but in the last part I have got a problem.

Here is my code below:

```
package yazdan;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Y {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("random number");
            frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1366, 727);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLayout(null);

            JLabel a = new JLabel("first number          :");
            a.setBounds(300, 250, 200, 70);
            frame.add(a);

            JLabel b = new JLabel("second number   :");
            b.setBounds(300, 350, 200, 70);
            frame.add(b);

            JTextField c = new JTextField();
            c.setEditable(true);
            c.setBounds(450, 250, 200, 70);
            frame.add(c);

            JTextField z = new JTextField();
            z.setEditable(true);
            z.setBounds(450, 350, 200, 70);
            frame.add(z);

            JButton y = new JButton("submit");
            y.setBounds(300, 450, 350, 70);
            frame.add(y);

            JLabel i = new JLabel("random number :");
            i.setBounds(700, 350, 350, 70);
            frame.add(i);

            JTextField h = new JTextField();
            h.setBounds(900, 350, 350, 70);
            h.setEditable(false);
            frame.add(h);

            y.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    y.addActionListener(this);
                    String first = c.getText();
                    String second = z.getText();
                    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(first);
                    if (i1 < 0) {
                        System.out.println("the numbers must be bigger than 0");
                    }
                    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(second);
                    if (i2 < 0) {
                        System.out.println("the numbers must be bigger than 0");
                    }
                    if (i1 > i2) {
                        System.out.println("the second number must be bigger than the first ");
                    } else {
                        int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(i1, i2 + 1);
                        String result = String.valueOf(n);
                        h.setText(result);
                    }
                }
            } // here is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

Here the problem is `""Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement""`

Comment: this place is to help you self debug the code. not for posting the whole code and expecting the community to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open that source code in an editor with syntax highlighting, then the colored marks will show where the error is:

```
y.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   ...
} // here is the problem
```

Count the number of open and closed brackets. One ")" is missing at the end.

Comment: thanks for your help but when i add a brackets eclipse say that you must delete it.

Comment: Try ```}); // here was the problem```

Comment: It solved my problem thanks a lot